# Printing the self designed PCB

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad, pcb-fabrication

I have designed the PCB on Eagle. Most of the components are SMD pakages. This is for the first time i have designed the PCB. I want to print this PCB in the industry (Chinese industry) but i have no idea how this works. What else do i have to mention except schematics and PCB layout. I have designed my own libraries so i am bit confused. I am sending design file with my friend and there is no way to contact any of the officials from the industry. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would need to output gerber files

Comment: Thank you for your Response but What are gerber files? Does eagle support these files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow [this](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/using-eagle-board-layout/generating-gerbers) tutorial to generate your gerber files. Then zip all the generated files and send them to manufacturer (or upload the zip to their website.) You don't need to send schematics or board drawings; gerber files are sufficient. [This](http://www.pcbway.com/) website is an example for online pcb quato. They review your gerber files and inform you if something is not OK.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use a batch boardhouse like [Oshpark](http://oshpark.com) that allows you to submit eagle .brd files directly, although it may be a good exercise to start running cam jobs and generating gerbers yourself.

Answer (score 2):

There's a price comparison site for PCB manufacturing, [PCBShopper.com](http://PCBShopper.com). Users can enter their board's specs - size, layers, preferred solder mask color, quantity, etc. - and PCBShopper will show them a list of over 20 PCB manufacturers in Asia, North America and Europe, along with prices and delivery times.

PCBShopper is free to use and is not affiliated with any manufacturers.